# Python fuzzy string matching as correlation style table/matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, fuzzy

I have a file with x number of string names and their associated IDs. Essentially two columns of data.

What I would like, is a correlation style table with the format x by x (having the data in question both as the x-axis and y axis), but instead of correlation, I would like the fuzzywuzzy library's function fuzz.ratio(x,y) as the output using the string names as input. Essentially running every entry against every entry.

This is sort of what I had in mind. Just to show my intent:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df = pd.read_csv('random_data_file.csv')

df = df[['ID','String']]
df['String_Dup'] = df['String'] #creating duplicate of data in question
df = df.set_index('ID')

df = df.groupby('ID')[['String','String_Dup']].apply(fuzz.ratio())
```

But clearly this approach is not working for me at the moment. Any help appreciated. It doesn't have to be pandas, it is just an environment I am relatively more familiar with.

I hope my issue is clearly worded, and really, any input is appreciated,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pandas' [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) function, followed by a column-wise [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to compute the fuzz.
This is considerably more elegant than my first answer.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# Create sample data frame.
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'abracadabra'), (2,'abc'), (3,'cadra'), (4, 'brabra')],
                  columns=['id', 'strings'])
# Create the cartesian product between the strings column with itself.
ct = pd.crosstab(df['strings'], df['strings'])
# Note: for pandas versions <0.22, the two series must have different names.
# In case you observe a "Level XX not found" error, the following may help:
# ct = pd.crosstab(df['strings'].rename(), df['strings'].rename())

# Apply the fuzz (column-wise). Argument col has type pd.Series.
ct = ct.apply(lambda col: [fuzz.ratio(col.name, x) for x in col.index])

# This results in the following:
#       strings      abc  abracadabra  brabra  cadra
#       strings
#       abc          100           43      44     25
#       abracadabra   43          100      71     62
#       brabra        44           71     100     55
#       cadra         25           62      55    100
```

For simplicity, I omitted the `groupby` operation as suggested in your question. In case need want to apply the fuzzy string matching on groups, simply create a separate function:

```
def cross_fuzz(df):
    ct = pd.crosstab(df['strings'], df['strings'])
    ct = ct.apply(lambda col: [fuzz.ratio(col.name, x) for x in col.index])
    return ct

df.groupby('id').apply(cross_fuzz)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as long as i do not attempt to cross tabulate the same series. i.e. i had to create a copy of 'strings' and call it something else, otherwise it gave me a 'level strings not found error'. 

I am happy to accept this as the answer otherwise.

Comment: The above code works for pandas 0.22.0. But you're right, former versions of pandas (e.g. 0.20.3) required the series to have different names. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

In pandas, the cartesian cross product between two columns can be created using a dummy variable and `pd.merge`. The `fuzz` operation is applied using `apply`. A final pivot operation will extract the format you had in mind. For simplicity, I omitted the `groupby` operation, but of course, you could apply the procedure to all group-tables by moving the code below into a separate function.

Here is what this could look like:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# Create sample data frame.
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'abracadabra'), (2,'abc'), (3,'cadra'), (4, 'brabra')],
                  columns=['id', 'strings'])

# Cross product, using a temporary column.
df['_tmp'] = 0
mrg = pd.merge(df, df, on='_tmp', suffixes=['_1','_2'])

# Apply the function between the two strings.
mrg['fuzz'] = mrg.apply(lambda s: fuzz.ratio(s['strings_1'], s['strings_2']), axis=1)

# Reorganize data.
ret = mrg.pivot(index='strings_1', columns='strings_2', values='fuzz')
ret.index.name = None 
ret.columns.name = None

# This results in the following:
#              abc  abracadabra  brabra  cadra
# abc          100           43      44     25
# abracadabra   43          100      71     62
# brabra        44           71     100     55
# cadra         25           62      55    100
```

Comment: way more smooth than crosstab. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import numpy as np  

input_file = csv.DictReader(open('random_data_file.csv')) 
string = []
for row in input_file: #file is appended row by row into a python dictionary
    string.append(row["String"]) #keys for the dict. are the headers



#now you have a list of the string values
length = len(string)
resultMat = np.zeros((length, length)) #zeros 2D matrix, with size X * X

for i in range (length):
    for j in range (length):
        resultMat[i][j] = fuzz.ratio(string[i], string[j])

print resultMat
```

I did the implementation in a *numby* 2D matrix. I am not that good in *pandas*, but I think what you were doing is adding another column and comparing it to the string column, meaning: string[i] will be matched with string_dub[i], all results will be 100

Hope it helps